# Dagster: handle TypedDict as op output

Tags: dagster

### Context

To keep track of the origin of my Dataframes, across my different ops, I defined `TaggedDF` as

```py
class TaggedDF(TypedDict):
    df: DataFrame
    ressource_name: str
```

So I could

```py
@op(retry_policy=OPS_RETRY_POLICY)
def read_fec(context, file_name: str) -> TaggedDF:
    """
    read fec files from source container
    """
    context.log.info("reading %s", file_name)

    reg = match(r".*\/(.*)FEC(.*)\.txt", file_name)
    blob_client_instance = azure_client.get_blob_client(
        Vars.LANDING_ZONE.value, file_name
    )
    blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(blob_data.content_as_text(encoding="UTF-8")), sep="\t")
    df["siren"] = reg.group(1)
    df["period"] = reg.group(2)
    return {"df": df, "ressource_name": file_name}
```

### Problem

Dagster does not seem to appreciate `TypedDict`

```
dagster._core.errors.DagsterTypeCheckError: Error occurred while type-checking output "result" of op "read_fec", with Python type <class 'dict'> and Dagster type TaggedDF
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dagster-30bqhDW5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/execute_plan.py", line 269, in dagster_event_sequence_for_step
    for step_event in check.generator(step_events):
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dagster-30bqhDW5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/execute_step.py", line 386, in core_dagster_event_sequence_for_step
    for evt in _type_check_and_store_output(step_context, user_event):
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dagster-30bqhDW5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/execute_step.py", line 436, in _type_check_and_store_output
    for output_event in _type_check_output(step_context, step_output_handle, output, version):
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dagster-30bqhDW5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/execute_step.py", line 282, in _type_check_output
    with user_code_error_boundary(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dagster-30bqhDW5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/errors.py", line 213, in user_code_error_boundary
    raise error_cls(
The above exception was caused by the following exception:

TypeError: TypedDict does not support instance and class checks
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dagster-30bqhDW5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/errors.py", line 206, in user_code_error_boundary
    yield
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dagster-30bqhDW5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/execute_step.py", line 287, in _type_check_output
    type_check = do_type_check(type_check_context, dagster_type, output.value)
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dagster-30bqhDW5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/execution/plan/execute_step.py", line 188, in do_type_check
    type_check = dagster_type.type_check(context, value)
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dagster-30bqhDW5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/types/dagster_type.py", line 171, in type_check
    retval = self._type_check_fn(context, value)
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dagster-30bqhDW5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/types/dagster_type.py", line 507, in type_check
    if not isinstance(value, expected_python_type):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 2385, in __subclasscheck__
    raise TypeError('TypedDict does not support instance and class checks')
```

How can I had this feature?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using pandas custom `attrs`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([])
df.attrs['ressource_name'] = 'read_fec'
print(df.attrs['ressource_name'])
```

Output:

```
read_fec
```

Note - if you save this to a file later in the code (csv, parquet, ...) the `attrs` won't persist in the file, but in your use case this won't be an issue.